# How to create <form> for search with assoc array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, search

Hello can u help me with a script that i have trouble with ;\ i want to create a search script from different columns and price range: so the search.php is that:

```
<?php
/* connect to the database*/
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "movie");
/* check connection */
if ($db->connect_errno) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error;
    exit();
}
$query="SELECT * FROM `filmi` 
         WHERE (`nomer` rlike '%$search%' OR 
                `rezume` rlike '%$search%' OR 
                `kategoriq` rlike '%$search%') AND 
                `seriq` BETWEEN '%$pricemin%' AND '$pricemax'  
         ORDER BY seriq ASC";
/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $db->prepare($query)) {
    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("sssdd", $search, $search, $search, $pricemin, $pricemax);
    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();
    /* get result */
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if ($result) {
    /* now you can fetch the results into an assoc array */
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row['nomer']. ", " .$row['rezume']. ", " .$row['kategoriq']. ", " .$row['seriq']. "<br>";
        }
    }
    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}
/* close db connection */
$db->close();

?>
```

What shoud be the "`<form method=?>`" form fill the $search and $pricemin / $pricemax fields ?

Comment: heay, do you want to fill $_REQUEST values in form's textboxes?

Comment: i menage to fill it but now when i didnt put any text for $search only put $pricemin / $pricemax it doesnt show any result :( can u help me with that ?

Comment: i would love to help you. But, i cant understand your problem. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: Well my problem is that when I search by keyword and price show me results but when looking only by price without a keyword I do not get any results. How can i make when i dont put any keyword for $search to show me all the content from the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether `$search` exists or not. Means, does there is some value in `$search` or not.

```
if(isset($search) && $search!=''){
    case 1
}
else{
    case 2
}
```

**Case 1**:
If there is value in $search then include it in where clause.
below query is an example to explain my idea.

```
$query="SELECT * FROM `filmi` 
     WHERE (`nomer` rlike '%$search%' OR 
            `rezume` rlike '%$search%' OR 
            `kategoriq` rlike '%$search%') AND 
            `seriq` BETWEEN '%$pricemin%' AND '$pricemax'  
     ORDER BY seriq ASC";
```

**Case 2:**
If there is no value in $search then does not include it in where clause.
check below query

```
$query="SELECT * FROM `filmi` 
     WHERE `seriq` BETWEEN '%$pricemin%' AND '$pricemax'  
     ORDER BY seriq ASC";
```

Comment: yes, i came to this conclusion but can u help me with the check code ?

Comment: i have updated the answer. But, its strange that after what you have written in question, you are asking me to help you with value checking code. Anyways, checkout answer now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `GET` or `POST` method in your `<form>` tagg

and

in your PHP script you can use `$form_var_name = $_REQUEST['form_var_name']` to access the data dispatched by form. To be more specific as follows

```
$search = $_REQUEST['search']; 
$pricemin = $_REQUEST['pricemin'];
$pricemax = $_REQUEST['pricemax'];
```

Comment: hmm i try it but it still doesnt show any results :( 
i make it that way:
`<form action="search.php" method="post" name="FormName" target="_self">
   Search: <input type="text" name="search" value="" size="24" border="0">

   
    
   <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Search" border="0">      <input type="reset" value="Reset" border="0"></p>
</form>`

and put $form_var_name = $_REQUEST['form_var_name'] before $query but i still wonder is this way  correct to put it into query --> '%$search%'

Comment: hmm its work but now another problem ;\ i need to put value for $search and $pricemax/min otherway its doesnt display any results i need to fill them :( can it works only with $search or only with $pricemax $pricemin ?